# Добавление Sentry в проект Vue2/Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, sentry

Всем привет, подскажите как подключить Sentry в проект vue/nuxt есть документация там пишут
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но куда его вставлять в связке vue/nuxt

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: хочу подключить sentry в проект на vue, как это сделать, и куда вставить данный код

Answer (score 0):

Во Vue в файл с входной точкой приложения. Вам прям код привели, как надо сделать – импортировать и инициализировать перед экземпляром Vue.

В Nuxt (2) можно воспользоваться пакетом [@nuxtjs/sentry](https://github.com/nuxt-community/sentry-module) или написать собственный плагин (но лучше пакетом – меньше проблем).

Comment: я правильно понимаю входная точка это ./layout/default.vue

Comment: @khodorPavel Странный вопрос. У вас что вообще, чистый Vue? Если да, то входной файл там, где создаётся экземпляр Vue (app.js, index.js или как-то ещё назван) – этот js-файл подгружается в шаблон HTML. Это точно НЕ файлы `.vue`

Comment: @khodorPavel Хотя по лэйауту я подозреваю, что у Вас всё же Nuxt. Ставьте пакет и не парьтесь. Инструкция там прилагается: https://sentry.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup